# java: represent range of float values on a color scale

Tags: java, colors, scale

I'm trying to create a function that will translate float values to a color. I created a simple linear scale:

```
float value;
float maxValue;

float scaleStep = maxValue / 5;

if (value < scaleStep) {
    color = blue
}

if (value > scaleStep && value <= scaleStep * 2) {
    color = green
}

if (value > scaleStep * 2 && value <= scaleStep * 3) {
    color = yellow
}

if (value > scaleStep * 3 && value <= scaleStep * 4) {
    color = orange
}

if (value > scaleStep * 4 && value <= scaleStep * 5) {
    color = red
}
```

but since most (but not all) of the values from the sets that I'm trying to represent are in close proximity from one particular value, graphical representation using linear scale isn't very useful (almost everything is translated to one color).

How can I create a non-linear scale so that differences between the values are more visible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have a set of numbers and you want to colour code them? Why not get the min and call it, say, WHITE. Get the max and call it RED and then assign all other numbers somewhere along the line in proportion to their distance from the minimum?

Comment: What do the values represent? You can't make a good visualization without taking this into account. Some people will undoubtedly suggest a rainbow scale - this is generally a bad idea. See for example http://researchweb.watson.ibm.com/people/l/lloydt/color/color.HTM

Comment: Consider using a mechanism to convert your color number into an HSV interpretation of the color space, then have your `value` interate over the "Hue" portion of the HSV color space.

Comment: values represent velocity of a moving object; the object usually travels at more or less the same speed but variations of speed are possible, and the object can also reduce its velocity to 0 at any given time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) is what you want. Interpolation generates samples between known samples in a dataset.

Here, your known samples are your colors; blue, green, yellow, orange, and red. The colors between those known colors are what you're looking for.

[Here's a link](http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/experiments/easing_function_generator.htm) to a nice visualizer of interpolation functions.

And here's a few interpolation functions for your convenience. Play with them, find the one that works best for you!

```
public float linearInterpolation(float start, float end, float normalizedValue) {
    return start + (end - start) * normalizedValue;
}

public float sinInterpolation(float start, float end, float normalizedValue){
    return (start+(end-start)* (1 - Math.cos(normalizedValue * Math.PI)) / 2;
}

//usage
linearInterpolation(red, green, .5f);//halfway between red and green.
//same with other demonstrations.
```

Edit:

Here, start and end refer to a starting and ending sample. The normalizedValue is some value between [0, 1] inclusive (that means it can equal exactly 0 or 1, or any value in between 0 and 1. That's what the term `normalized` means typically.)

So, for you, `start` and `end` will be two colors, and `normalizedValue` will represent how near you are to the starting or ending color.

Take linearInterpolation for example.

```
red = 1;
green = 2;
float midway = 1 + (2 - 1) * .5;
//midway = 1.5, which is halfway between red and green.
float allRed = 1 + (2 - 1) * 0;
//allRed = 1, which is the value of red (or start)
float allGreen = 1 + (2 - 1) * 1;
//allGreen = 2, which is the value of green (or end)
```

So, for linear interpolation, the closer the `normalizedValue` is to 1, the nearer the returned value it is to `end`. The closer `normalizedValue` is to 0, the closer the returned value is to `start`.

This isn't necessarily true for other interpolation functions. You can think linear interpolation as a simple line segment connecting values. Want a value halfway between those segments? Use a normalized value of .5, viola!

Other functions might have steeper slopes, or even oscillate between `start` and `end`!

Try and stop thinking in terms of color, and start thinking more abstractly. Colors are a certain distance apart. Interpolation helps you define what values lie in the distance between them.

Comment: do 'start' and 'end' refer to minimum and maximum values in the set? math isn't my strongest skill, could you please explain the meaning of 'normalizedValue'?

Comment: Edited answer. I hope this helps. Interpolation is a powerful tool once you understand it.

Comment: I linked to those and did give an example of sine interpolation.

Comment: Also his code isn't linear interpolation as ive described. Its piecewise and would result in a saw tooth look.

Comment: @William Morrison  Removed my comment.  Sorry I didn't notice.

Comment: @William Morrison  I think you mean staircase.  I prefer to call this kind of functions "discrete".

Comment: Ah, difference of wording. Inignificant, I think overall we agree.

Answer (score 1):

Since the float values are in a set, you know how many there are and can calculate a color interval. You can then iterate over them, assigning colors and incrementing by the color interval.

Edit: The downside of this approach is that the same float value will not map to the same color when the number of values changes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a logarithmic scale. If you use base 10 logs, the range will be from -39 to +39.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution, a double or triple log can be better.  I made a very quick test, and for the sample `{ 1.00, 1.20, 1.10, 1.05, 1.15, 9.70, 1.20, 2.00, 1.01, 1.03, 1.16, 1.02, 9.00, 1.20, 1.10, 1.50, 1.05, 1.15, 2.00, 3.00 }`, function

```
int f(float x) {
    return (int)(Math.log(Math.log(x)*100+1)*2.5) ;
}
```

Produces the following distribution:

```
f(x)  color   count
 0    blue      4
 1    green     4
 2    yellow    6
 3    orange    3
 4    red       3
```

Not bad for 5 minutes of work.  However, if you post a reasonable sample of numbers (say 100), a distribution graph, or, much better, a distribution histogram, we could help you better.  The trick is to find the distribution function of the data.  From that function it is very easy to come with a second function that makes the distribution uniform ("flat").

Answer (score 0):

A second alternative in your case (which is relatively simple as you want to use just a few colors), is to use `scaleStep`s of different "width".

```
if( value < greenMin ) color= blue ;
else if( value < yellowMin ) color= green ;
else if( value < orangeMin ) color= yellow ;
else if( value < redMin ) color = orange ;
else color= red ;
```

I took the liberty of condensing the code a bit.  Let me know if it's not clear.  You need to determine the values of greenMin, yellowMin, orangeMin, and redMin, of course.  For that, grab a big, representative data sample, sort it, and divide it in 5 groups of equal size.  The first value of the second group is greenMin, first value of the third is yellowMin, and so on.  You can use an office spreadsheet program to do this, as it's a one-time activity.